# Parallel Caffe installation : This MPI version is NOT support multi-thread! *

Tags: multithreading, mpi, caffe

The mpi_train.sh has the following line:

mpiexec.hydra -prepend-rank -host node11 -n 16

While running examples/cifar10/mpi_train_quick.sh in parallel caffe I get the following error:

```
F0521 18:33:32.101737 16179 caffe.cpp:293] This MPI version is NOT support multi-thread!
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
@ 0x7f8367e83daa (unknown)
@ 0x7f8367e83ce4 (unknown)
@ 0x7f8367e836e6 (unknown)
@ 0x7f8367e86687 (unknown)
@ 0x410ac8 main
@ 0x7f8364b76ec5 (unknown)
@ 0x414e77 (unknown)
@ (nil) (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have installed mpich-3.1.4 version.
When I do which mpirun, which mpiexec, which mpicc, I get the path to the mpich-3.1.4 folder from all of these
Also the system has both Open-Mpi and MPICH-3.1.4 installed since open-mpi gets installed automatically while installing opencv which is a pre-requisite for parallel caffe . How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Call MPI_Init_thread properly.

Comment: Actually there was another library of openmpi installed in usr/local folder which was not configured for multi threading. Specifying the path to the correct library solved this error :)